# Overlaying one animation on another in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

So I want to make two animations and place them on top of each other. I want to do so because I want different frame rates for both. How can this be done if I'm using funcAnimation in matplotlib? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a test inside the update function of the fastest changing animation, and only in case the frame number is a multiple of the ratio between the time steps, update the second animation.

The example below has a moving sine wave. Every 10<sup>th</sup> step a scaled cosine function is updated.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(0, 6 * np.pi, 200)
line1, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))
line2, = ax.plot(x, np.cos(x) / 100)

def animate(i):
    line1.set_ydata(np.sin(x + i / 10.0))  # update the first part
    if i % 10 == 0:
        j = i / 10
        line2.set_ydata(np.cos(x) * j / 20)  # update the second part, only every 5 steps
    return line1, line2,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 200), interval=25)
plt.show()
```